# How to rewrite url in django

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

I'm restricting the way in which you get to my customer portal to force customers to the main site to increase daily traffic. However, I'm trying to figure out how to re-write a url in django but im not quite sure how.

The docs are kinda consufing on this subject. The url I want to re-write is **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?enki=0011`**

I need to take off the part that is ?enki=0011 because that is essentially the check. If the user has that in the url when they visit the login page it will allow them to login. However if they don't it will redirect them to the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a redirect will "remove" the querystring from the url.  The storefront view checks if that querystring is in the url, sets a flag in the session, then redirects.  If that string isn't there, and the session flag isn't set, it redirects back to the other website.

```
def storefront(request):
    if request.GET.get('enki') == '0011':
        request.session['from_main_site'] = True
        return redirect('storefront')
    elif not request.session.get('from_main_site'):
        return redirect('http://main-site.com/')

    # at this point the user has come from the main site
    # and doesn't have "enki" in the url

    return render(request, 'storefront.html')
```